# Getting size of a list in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list on my controller. I want its size in javascript function. How to get it?

Comment: If you are calling javascript function of Visualforce page then you can get the size in visualforce and pass it to your javascript function as an parameter.

Comment: please post your code or the related code snippet, so everyone can understand root cause of your issue

Answer (score 2):

I would expect it'll be something like this in the HTML

The use of JSEncode is probably not necessary, but if you are mixing VF output and Javascript it's a good practice.

```
<script>
   var myJavascriptVariable = {!JSENCODE(myVisualforceList.size)};
</script>
```

Comment: Getting incorrect syntax error

Comment: You can bind `list.size` but only for lists you've declared. You can't call size for a related list on an SObject, i.e. `Account.Contacts.size` is not gonna happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your javascript - 
alert({!lstMySampleList}.length);